# Getting closest number to 0 and can be negative number

Tags: python, arrays

I have the below range and I want to pick the number closets to `0`. in the below array, `-4` would be the closet number and the right answer. Thanks in advance

```
num_array = [-37,-24,-18,-10,-4,5,12,18,26]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the ***smallest*** ***positive*** and the ***largest*** ***negative*** number. If `0` is not there in the list then select the closest one from the two numbers mentioned above.

```
import sys
a = [-37,-24,-18,-10,-4,5,12,18,26]
maxn = sys.maxsize
minn = -sys.maxsize - 1
f = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 0:
        ans = 0
        f = 1
        break
    elif a[i] > 0 and a[i] < maxn :
        maxn = a[i]
    elif a[i] < 0 and a[i] > minn :
        minn = a[i]
    else:
        None
if f == 0:
    if abs(maxn) < abs(minn):
        ans = maxn
    else:
        ans = minn
print(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as I had anticipated!! Very cool trick though, will keep this in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 4):

Let us do `min` and pass the selection via `key`

```
min(num_array, key=lambda x:abs(x-0))
-4
```

Check with -1..

```
num_array = [-37,-24,-18,-10,-4,5,12,18,26,-1]
min(num_array, key=lambda x:abs(x-0))
-1
```

Comment: @JonClements...I am not sure I get you , but the -1 will return ..

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm not understanding but that gives me -1 but that is not a choice in the array...

Comment: The -1 example is just showing a closer value than -4. +1 would have been a better example to show that it works for values larger than zero too (because it uses abs). This answer is correct although I'm not sure why zero is being subtracted.

Comment: @PaulWhipp *I want to pick the number closets to 0*

Comment: That is exactly what this solution does. You don't need to subtract zero - that is a 'no op'

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. Closest to 0 and is one of the numbers in the array..